# In Android, how to link the address of sms to the contact?

Tags: android, sms, contacts

The address of content://sms is the phone number, but it has several variables. For example, it could contain blank, -, (, ), and it can also contain the country call code in front of the number.

Below is a detail sample. The phone number in contact is +yy xxxxxxx. The address in content://sms includes xxxxxxx, +yy xxxxxxx, xxx-xxxx, xxx xxxx. So how to connect the records of sms to the contact for the above cases?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just look for the string that starts with "+" and compare that with your contact?

Comment: It can resolve most of the case, but not all. For example, the contact's phone number is xxxxxxx. And the address in sms is +yyxxxxxxx. Then how to handle this case?